# How can I set a cell's background color using an array[x][y] indication on google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a function that will set a background color of a cell if it stands in some conditions using an array to get the cell position

**The logic is as follows:** if the priority of the task is urgent and the time duration is higher than 4, than color the "time duration" relative cell in red.

**Here is the google sheet table:**

[image]

For that I'm using a sub function called "FindColumn" that its purpose is the bring me the X and Y positions of the needed columns.

After that I'm using the array "values" to check the above condition.
When the conditions are found i want to change the color and for that I'm trying to use the **setBackground** function but, if i understood correctly, this function cant run over an array.

Is there a way i can color the cell using this function or maybe other function?
Maybe there is a way that i can transform my array to a range that setBackground can use?

Thanks a lot

Note:
I don't want to use conditional formatting for that.

Note that according to this table, cell 'B4' should be marked as red since "Edit chart" task is matched with the above condition

**Here is the main function that should paint the cell:**

```js
function verificationTest() {
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lastCell = activeSheet.getRange(activeSheet.getMaxRows(), activeSheet.getMaxColumns());
var searchRange = activeSheet.getRange("A1:Z");
var values = searchRange.getValues();
var columnIndex = FindColumn("Priority");
var columnIndex2 = FindColumn("Time Duration");
//console.log ("columnIndex: "+columnIndex + ", columnIndex2: "+columnIndex2)
 for (x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
   if (values[x][columnIndex].includes("Urgent")) {
    console.log ("includes");
    if(values[x][columnIndex2]>4) {
    console.log("bad");
    values[x][columnIndex2].setBackground('red');
    
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Here is the function that returns the X and Y positions of a requested header:

```js
function FindColumn (lookfor) {
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lastCell = activeSheet.getRange(activeSheet.getMaxRows(), activeSheet.getMaxColumns());
var searchRange = activeSheet.getRange("A1:Z1");
var values = searchRange.getValues();
for (x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < values[x].length; y++) {
    if(values[x][y]== lookfor){
      return (y)
      break;
    
  }
}
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set background to an array!

Try

```
activeSheet.getRange(x+1,columnIndex2+1).setBackground('red')
```

script :

```
function verificationTest() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var searchRange = activeSheet.getRange("A1:Z");
  var values = searchRange.getValues();
  var columnIndex = FindColumn("Priority");
  var columnIndex2 = FindColumn("Time Duration");
  for (x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
    if (values[x][columnIndex].includes("Urgent")) {
      if (values[x][columnIndex2] > 4) {
        activeSheet.getRange(x+1,columnIndex2+1).setBackground('red')
      }
    }
  }
}
function FindColumn(lookfor) {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var searchRange = activeSheet.getRange("A1:Z1");
  var values = searchRange.getValues();
  for (x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < values[x].length; y++) {
      if (values[x][y] == lookfor) {
        return (y)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To set the background of cells in an array, use [.setBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackgrounds(String))

```js
const verificationTest = () => {

const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
const values = range.getValues();
const priorityCol = values[0].indexOf('Priority');
const durationCol = values[0].indexOf('Time Duration');
const backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds().map((r, i) => r.map ( (c, j) => 
j == durationCol && values[i][durationCol] > 4 && values[i][priorityCol].includes('Urgent') ? 'red' : 'white'
))
range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds)
}
```